# If $\mathrm{E}(|X|^p)$ is finite, show that $\mathrm{E}(|X-q|^p)$ is finite for $p \geq 0, q \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable, $p \geq 0$, and $\mathrm{E}(|X|^p)$ be finite. Show that $\mathrm{E}(|X-q|^p)$ is finite for any $q \in \mathbb{R}$.

By definition of expectation, if we first assume $X$ is discrete,
$$\mathrm{E}(|X-q|^p) = \sum_{x} |x-q|^p f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is the distribution of $X$.

We can break this up into
$$\mathrm{E}(|X-q|^p) = \sum_{|x|\leq|q|} |x-q|^p f(x) + \sum_{|x|>|q|} |x-q|^p f(x).$$

In the first sum, $|x-q|^p$ is bounded by $|2q|^p$, and thus the sum is bounded by that as well.

For the second sum, I want to use the fact that $\mathrm{E}(|X|^p) = \sum_x |x|^p f(x)$ is bounded by something, but I'm unsure how. I considered that $|x-q|^p \leq (|x|+|q|)^p$. Any thoughts?

Comment: $|x-q|^p \leq (|x|+|q|)^p \leq (2|x|)^p \leq 2^p|x|^p$ ?

Comment: Oh right, because $|x| > |q|$ we can say that. I'm blind...

Answer (score 0):

For any $x,y\in\mathbb R$, we have $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|\le2\max\{|x|,|y|\}$, and so
$$|x+y|^p\le\Big(2\max\{|x|,|y|\}\Big)^p=2^p\max\{|x|^p,|y|^p\}\le2^p(|x|^p+|y|^p).$$
Using the above inequality and monotonicity of expectation, one finds
$$E(|X-q|^p)\le E\Big(2^p(|X|^p+q^p)\Big)=2^pE(|X|^p)+(2q)^p<\infty.$$
The assumption that $X$ is discrete does not particularly simplify the problem.